# What wire size is used on the Adafruit Ultra Bright 3 Watt Chainable NeoPixel LEDs?

Tags: power, ws2811

We are talking about these guys:

[image]

https://www.adafruit.com/product/4544

The current carrying capacity of those wires puts a limit on how long of a string you can have from a single power source.

Comment: Supply power from both ends or you'll see the lights gradually get dimmer down the length of the chain.

Answer (score 1):

20 AWG

[image]

That means they can carry about 10A...

https://learnmetrics.com/wire-gauge-chart-amp-wire-sizes/

So if each pixel uses [about 0.5A](https://www.google.com/search?q=3%20watts%2F5%20volts&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS881US882&oq=3%20watts%2F5%20volts&aqs=chrome..69i57j6.2805j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) then you can have a string of about 20 long before this becomes a problem.

Note that if you are not using full 100% white the power usage per pixel will be lower.

No info on the current carry capacity of the JST connectors, but should be approximately in line.